# Easy Example Flash Builder Actionscript 3 Programming

Tags: actionscript, flash-builder

I really need help with this! I have looked high and low for an easy example I can learn from and can't find anything. I am turning to here as a last resort. I know there are plenty of examples of coverflow with images so there must be a way.

I am creating an online store with Flash Builder 4 and need to load product images into an TileGroup Container for display to whoever visits the app web page. The images will be stored in a directory so the app will need to read the directory to get the file image names and load them into the Tile Group Container. I do not want to hard code the image names and I do not want to use Adobe Air.

Can anyone help give me a lucid example that might be simple enough for me to learn from and understand as a newbie?
Thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this  by using a combination of PHP and AS3.

I don't think it's possible to read the content of a directory with AS3 without using Air, but it's possible to do it with PHP.

This would mean calling a PHP function from AS3 when you initialize your application. Get the PHP function to return XML or JSON. Parse the returned data and load the files, then display them.

[gotoandlearn.com](http://gotoandlearn.com/) has a few examples about communication between AS3 & PHP as well as carrousel/coverflow examples.

If you're not familiar with PHP, I'm sure you can find some help here with regard to the exact function you would need to return the directory content, but in any case , it shouldn't be too difficult to come up with your own.

Hope this helps!